# LinearLayout is showing second item in middle, instead of right underneath first item and the last item (Button) is at the button of the screen

Tags: android

I have a vertical LinearLayout with 2 fragments and a button. How can I get it so the 3 items are on top of each other, without spaces? 
Right now the first fragment is on top.
Second fragment drawn in the center
last item (button)  drawn at the buttom of the screen

xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/idBuySell"
    android:name="com.example.mylibrary.fraBuySell"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />
```

first fragment xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/menHome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text=" HOME " />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:text=" | " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/menEditKey"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text=" Edit Keys " />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:text=" | " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/menNewOrder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text=" New Order " />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:text=" | " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/menBot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text=" Bot " />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:text=" | " />

<TextView android:id="@+id/menOpenOrders"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text=" Open Orders " />
```

second fragmen t xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idPriceName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cost:" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/idPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="0.0" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Volumn:" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/idVol"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="1.0" />
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/idOrder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Place Order" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"`.

This way, only the `android:layout_weight="1"` will be used by the system to compute the height of your item.